# Can't select columns with dplyr::select

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

While trying to replicate some examples from the dplyr's github README I've found myself stuck with an error

```
Error: object 'vctrs_new_data_frame' not found
```

Error came after running this code on the console:

```
starwars %>% select(name, ends_with("color"))
```

Using some other datasets I get the same error. Here goes my `sessionInfo` results:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Ecuador.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Ecuador.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Ecuador.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                     LC_TIME=Spanish_Ecuador.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.4          RevoUtils_11.0.3     RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        crayon_1.3.4      assertthat_0.2.1  R6_2.4.1          magrittr_1.5      pillar_1.4.3.9000
 [7] rlang_0.4.4       rstudioapi_0.11   vctrs_0.2.3       tools_3.6.0       glue_1.3.1        purrr_0.3.3      
[13] compiler_3.6.0    pkgconfig_2.0.3   pbdZMQ_0.3-3      tidyselect_1.0.0  tibble_2.1.3
```

Can it be a conflict between package and R version? Because while loading the `tidyverse` I get the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
3: package ‘tibble’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
4: package ‘tidyr’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
5: package ‘readr’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
6: package ‘purrr’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
7: package ‘stringr’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
8: package ‘forcats’ was built under R version 3.6.2
```

Comment: What is the output of `head(vctrs_new_data_framevctrs_new_data_frame)`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error, maybe if you restart R it will go away?

Comment: There is no `vctrs_new_data_frame` on my environment. My guess is it has something to do with the `select` calling of the `vctrs` package.

Comment: I've restarted several times, close the project I'm working with and restarted R but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: As we can't reproduce the error with the information you are giving it's going to be very difficult to help you. It *looks like* you overwrote some internal function, but it's hard to tell what is the *actual* reason for your problem. Only thing I can suggest is closing the IDE, making sure that no environment is saved and re-used and restart R again.

Comment: I also can't reproduce with CRAN versions of dplyr and vctrs.  Maybe try reinstalling the packages?

Comment: Sounds like you should upgrade to R 3.6.2!

Comment: What is `RevoUtils`? I'd start by detaching that (and `RevoUtilsMath`). Then clear the environment (`rm(list=ls())`).

Comment: Go to minute 10 of this for some reasons `rm(list=ls())` isn't as reliable as restarting R:  https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2020/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable-jenny-bryan

Comment: Run `conflicts()` to see if you are actually using `dplyr::select` or something else

Comment: I guess the problem got resolved.

Comment: Not by itself :) I reinstalled all my libraries and got it solved somehow. Thanks!